# Why is NSArray objectAtIndex:section for tableView titleForHeaderInSection error: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsarray

It's so wierd:

_tableDataSectionTitles is a property of this UITableViewController subclass & an NSArray.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSLog(@"%@", _tableDataSectionTitles); // returns: ( "string" )
NSLog(@"%@", [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:0]); // returns: "string"
NSLog(@"%i", section); // returns 0
NSLog(@"%@", [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]; // returns "string"
return [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]; // returns: *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

what's with that!? (everything else is working properly. I checked. Thrice.) (seriously though, this is like the first thing that it runs through, so nothing should be wrong here)

I've also tried it with out even using the array:

```
NSString *rep = [[NSString alloc] init];
if (section == 0) {
    rep = @"Stuff";
} else { // doesn't even need it - it won't run through it anyway
    //rep = [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]; // commented out just to not have any doubts
}
return rep;
```

but still the same error. help!

Comment: if(section == 0) { return [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]; } else { return "whatever you want" }

Comment: Paste in the actual output that appears in your debug console from those NSLogs.  Don't try to retype it as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got it.

So, turns out that my _tableDataSectionContents array was empty while the _tableDataSectionTitles had one in it. so, I still don't understand why exactly it raised the error for a completely separate array, but it works now! thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to detect the wrong part of your code easly

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  NSString *title = @"Empty";

  NSLog(@"count: %d", [_tableDataSectionTitles count]); 
  NSLog(@"section: %d", section);

  if([_tableDataSectionTitles count] > section)
      title = [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]

  return title; 

}
```

Comment: log output: (-   count: 1    -    section: 0    -    *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array    -) so it's still the same thing. erroring at title = [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]

Comment: please check the tableDataSectionTitles scope and its contents

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the error says `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`
meaning, the array IS empty even though it shouldn't be. So am not sure  what exactly the problem is but you can follow the following steps to debug the problem,

1. Check if it happening only for section 0. Instead of passing section to objectAtIndex, pass 0 and try.
2. Return the title only if the array is not empty,

   if([_tableDataSectionTitles count] > 0)
   {
     return [_tableDataSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
   }
   else
   {
     return @"Default Title";
   }
3. Have alloc init the array somewhere in your code..? may e in ViewDidLoad or the init method.? If not do that and try.

If you encounter again anything weird, let us know. Hope it helps..:)

Comment: well, I have tried putting it with the number 0, & also with the if statemet. However, (It's really wierd) when I put the method in an NSLog with either or both of the methods (0 & section) It returns fine, but when I call either method outside (even in the if statement) it ends up with the same error. - not to mention that the NSLog is just one line above the method call.